# If condition is not working correctly in validation test

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've programmed validation test but the `if` condition is satisfied
even though it is not supposed to.

Here is my code:

```js
function chk_val() {

  var name = $('.info .name').val();
  var birth = $('.info .birth').val();
  var phone = $('.info .phone').val();
  var eng_kor = /^[가-힣a-z]+$/gi;
  var num = /^[0-9]+$/g;

  if (name == '' || birth == '' || phone == '') {
    alert('1');
  } else if (!eng_kor.test(name)) {
    alert('2');
  } else if (!num.test(birth)) {
    alert('3');
  } else if (birth.length != 8) {
    alert('4');
  } else if (!num.test(phone)) {
    alert('5');
  } else if (phone.length != 10 && phone.length != 11) {
    alert('6');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <input class="name" type="text" />
  <input class="birth" type="text" maxlength="8" />
  <input class="phone" type="text" maxlength="11" />
</div>
<button onclick="chk_val()">Check</button>
```

I wrote my `name` (`wonki`), `birth` (`19890222`) and `phone` (`01012341234`), then clicked the `button(onclick="chk_val()")`. It could pass all of the `if` statements, but it got caught in `alert('3')` or `alert('5')`.

I used `console.log` to check the value of `num.test(birth)` and `num.test(phone)`, and it comes out TRUE.

I don't know why I cannot pass `if(!num.test(birth))` and `if(!num.test(phone))`.

Comment: When I try the snippet I get `alert(4)` because the birth date isn't 8 digits.

Comment: Don't use the `g` modifier when you're using `test()`.

Comment: Don't use else if, use if. Since you want to check everything. If you use else if, it can only alert once and stops checking for another else if

Comment: oh sorry I modified the birth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you need to remove the global flag(/g) from the regex.

> If the regex has the global flag set, test() will advance the
>   lastIndex of the regex. A subsequent use of test() will start the
>   search at the substring of str specified by lastIndex (exec() will
>   also advance the lastIndex property). It is worth noting that the
>   lastIndex will not reset when testing a different string.

[Reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Answer (score 1):

you need to change just RegExp for number

```js
function chk_val() {

  var name = $('.info .name').val();
  var birth = $('.info .birth').val();
  var phone = $('.info .phone').val();
  var eng_kor = /^[가-힣a-z]+$/gi;
  var num = new RegExp('^\\d+$');

  if (name == '' || birth == '' || phone == '') {
    alert('1');
  } else if (!eng_kor.test(name)) {
    alert('2');
  } else if (!num.test(birth)) {
    alert('3');
  } else if (birth.length != 8) {
    alert('4');
  } else if (!num.test(phone)) {
    alert('5');
  } else if (phone.length != 10 && phone.length != 11) {
    alert('6');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <input class="name" type="text" />
  <input class="birth" type="text" maxlength="8" />
  <input class="phone" type="text" maxlength="11" />
</div>
<button onclick="chk_val()">Check</button>
```